# how to get columns in a table in mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I create a table in my database using this code

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db); 
$sql = "CREATE TABLE My_Table(";
for($i = 1; $i<=50 ; $i++) {
    if($i!=50)
        $sql .= "id_".$i." INT(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',";
    else
        $sql .= "id_".$i." INT(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0')";
}

if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    echo "Done";
}
```

Now I have `$var = 10;` and I want to get for example `id_10` and change the value of `id_10` to `id_10+=$var`.

I'm a beginner in PHP/MySQL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you question is nor clear, what actually u want? do u like to create 50 fields in a table?

Comment: I would ask why are creating a table on a execution time in php? Are you creating some sort of sql manager like phpMyAdmin? Besides, your script is wrong because you are not finishing the create command properly. It never will close the create statement and the last column will have an extra comma.

Comment: do you like to rename the column name by using php?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a decent schema. You're probably a lot better of having a table with an index and the value (so there's one line per value) rather than 50 columns.

Comment: @Jorge it doesn't have extra comma look at if / else . i close_mysql  i have a table and i add 50 columns to it now i want to change the value of id_i

Comment: @user3682067 Yes it does. `$i` never reaches 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select:

```
my $stmt = $con->prepare($con,"SELECT id_".$var." FROM My_table WHERE ...");
$stmt->bind_param($stmt, /* something here which depends on what you need for your condition */ );
$stmt->execute();
```

update:

```
my $stmt = $con->prepare($con,"UPDATE My_table SET id_".$var."=id_".$var."+? FROM My_table WHERE ...");
$stmt->bind_param($stmt,"i",$var /* to be changed depending on condition */);
$stmt->execute();
```

Note that you **must** make sure that $i is very strictly checked if it comes from the browser (`$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`...). Otherwise that opens the door to horrible SQL injection errors.

But note my comment above, I don't think this is a good schema.